# Is it possible to prevent Windows Explorer from locking up when hovering a file during drag and drop above a network drive that is offline?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-explorer, network-shares, drag-and-drop

In Windows Explorer in the left sidebar I have a link to a network drive that is usually turned off. If I want to drag an drop a file from that window to another window, I have to take special care that I don't accidentally touch that specific shortcut or else the explorer window will completely lock up for about 30 seconds, forcing me to wait, probably because windows attempts to connect to that drive thinking I want to drop something there and that waiting for a timeout and causing the window to lock. Is there a way to: prevent windows from trying to connect immediately upon me accidentally touching that shortcut OR shorten the timeout OR have the sidebar folders collapsed by default OR hide a linked network drive only from the sidebar, but still have it in My Computer? Though I actually want it in the sidebar.

Comment: You can make that network drive available offline, and the problem will go away. But it doesn't work reliably into reconnecting when the drive becomes online again, so it brings different problems. Its up to you what is more convenient. A different approach is to actually remove the share and map it every time you use it and stop using it. This can be done with a simple batch script.

Comment: Offline availability is not an option, the drive is 24TB in capacity.

Comment: You don't actually have to make the entire drive available offline. A single file can be made available offline too, but if windows doesn't detect that the drive is online, it is going to be hard to get the connection back. But at least it will no longer be a problem to wait when hovering. You can try it, and disable offline files if its not a solution you can work with.

Comment: There's another option, but its a bit more advanced. You remove your drive mapping, then use `mklink /j linkname \\networkpath\share` to create a junction. You now have to navigate to a folder in order to access the network share. If you share that folder and map that share to a drive letter, the network mapping in your pc is local so it's always online.

Comment: This is a serious issue and windows still doesn't have an answer to this.